# I want to replace H2 - H5 tags into P by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with replacing tags. Plugin automatically gets title as h2 tag, and that title is shoved into Table of content which I don't want.

[h2 tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpSSA.png)

Tried with this code, but not working for me:

```
$('.faq-main-title h2').replaceWith(function () {
  return "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";
});
```

[Here is how it looks, added custom class faqsectionparagraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCZPW.png)

Comment: your selector looks incorrect, seems like it should be: `$('h2.faq-main-title')`

Comment: because the class is _on_ the h2 tag, you need to have `h2` and the class selector `.faq-main-title` connected. Your selector currently means "target the `<h2>` tag within the elements which have the class `.faq-main-title`, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how to replace h5 with p

```
var htmlEl = $('h5').html()

$('h5').replaceWith("<p>" + htmlEl + "</p>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/k5290u43/2/

Answer (score -1):

This works.

```js
$('.faq-main-title h2').replaceWith(function () {
return "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-main-title">
<h2>hello</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: So it's not an answer :)

Comment: If you can't reproduce it's better to vote to close the question (for clarity, for being non-reproducable, etc): [Are "Your code works fine for me" answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277924)